# Find ActiveRecord object by class name and id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a polymorphic association with votes, comments and posts, like this:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, as: :voteable
end
```

When I click on the upvote link, I send `voteable_type` and `voteable_id` in the params. In the votes controller I want to find the voteable object using these two strings, but the only solution I've found is eval. I figure that evaling strings from the params is not a great idea.

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def find_voteable
    @voteable = eval("#{params[:vote][:voteable_type]}.find(params[:vote][:voteable_id])")
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on how to find an ActiveRecord object by class name and id? Or alternatively, is there a better way to go about doing this that is not sending stuff in the params?

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use

```
params[:vote][:voteable_type].classify.constantize.find(params[:vote][:voteable_id])
```

or also

```
Object.const_get(params[:vote][:voteable_type]).find(params[:vote][:voteable_id])
```

also check

http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

Answer (score 6):

This isn't a direct answer your question, but I would like to challenge your design and suggest a different approach: I would add two independent `vote` methods to both controllers (`posts_controller` and `comments_controller`), something like:

```
# in posts_controller.rb
def vote
  Post.find(params[:id]).vote
end
```

I think this is much easier to read and to understand. Furthermore it allows simple and clear restful URLs. Define routes like this in your `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts do
  post 'vote', on: :member
end
```

Plus it gives you path helpers like `vote_post_path(@post)` which build nice readable URLs like `/posts/1/vote`.

Comment: I would definitely choose this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Would the [`const_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Module.html#method-i-const_get) work for you?

```
if const_defined? params[:vote][:voteable_type]
  votable = const_get params[:vote][:voteable_type]
  votable.find params[:vote][:voteable_id]
end
```